# Rest api authentication for drupal 7 endpoint issue

Tags: php, rest, drupal

I have created a rest api for my project to expose a view which is working when iam in same browser.

when iam testing via postman iam not able to do any thing.

**module:service**

[image]

Comment: change authentification method , and test if it's the same ?

Comment: i have tried with al authentication methods.. its not working for any of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i was able to download http basic access module for services and get the desired output*.

**1)install the package.

2)go to service edit select http

3)goto http://localhost/api/v2/abc-json  -{api/v2} is endpoint
4)enter username and password in popup**

> Thats it